# Replace zeros with mean of non-zeros along an axis of array - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

How can I replace 0s of the first rows by mean of the remaining rows?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer


data = np.array([[0,0,0,0,3,2,4,4,0], 
                  [4,6,8,9,3,1,1,4,0],
                  [4,6,8,9,3,1,1,4,0]]) 
print (data.shape)

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean')
res = imputer.fit_transform(data) 
print (res)

[[4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 2. 4. 4.]
 [4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 1. 1. 4.]
 [4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 1. 1. 4.]]
```

But, should not drop any column.

Expected result is:

```
[[4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 2. 4. 4. 0]
 [4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 1. 1. 4. 0]
 [4. 6. 8. 9. 3. 1. 1. 4. 0]]
```

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: By `first rows`, do you mean replace only for the first row?

Comment: yes, at least to replace 0s of first row is ok

Comment: What if there any zeros in other rows, how would the mean be computed?

Comment: using other remaining non zero values, if exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just indexing should be enough for what you want:

```
m = data[0] == 0
data[0, m] = data[1:,m].mean(0)

print(data)

array([[4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0],
       [4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0],
       [4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0]])
```

---

To fill all zeros from the means of all other rows and *excluding zeroes* from the mean, we could use a masked array:

```
m = data == 0
means = np.ma.array(data, mask = m).mean(0)
data + m * means.data

array([[4., 6., 8., 9., 3., 2., 4., 4., 0.],
       [4., 6., 8., 9., 3., 1., 1., 4., 0.],
       [4., 6., 8., 9., 3., 1., 1., 4., 0.]])
```

---

**Update**

To fill with the mean of the other columns, you could similarly do:

```
m = data == 0
means = np.ma.array(data, mask = m).mean(1)
data + m * means.data[:,None]

array([[3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.  , 2.  , 4.  , 4.  , 3.25],
       [4.  , 6.  , 8.  , 9.  , 3.  , 1.  , 1.  , 4.  , 4.5 ],
       [4.  , 6.  , 8.  , 9.  , 3.  , 1.  , 1.  , 4.  , 4.5 ]])
```

Comment: great, thank you. By the way, how to replace if there are 0s in other rows, by calculating mean of non zero values, if there are.

Comment: Accepted and voted! Can it be filled by column wise as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with `axis` param for applying it along a generic axis -

```
def fill0s(data, axis):
    m = data!=0
    s = data.sum(axis, keepdims=True)
    c = m.sum(axis, keepdims=True)
    c[c==0] = 1 # to avoid warning of division by 0
    return np.where(m,data,s/c)
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: data
Out[143]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 4, 0],
       [4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0],
       [6, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0],
       [0, 6, 8, 9, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0]])

In [144]: fill0s(data,axis=0)
Out[144]: 
array([[5., 6., 8., 9., 3., 2., 4., 4., 0.],
       [4., 6., 8., 9., 3., 1., 1., 4., 0.],
       [6., 6., 8., 9., 3., 1., 1., 4., 0.],
       [5., 6., 8., 9., 3., 1., 1., 4., 0.]])

In [147]: fill0s(data,axis=1)
Out[147]: 
array([[3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.25, 3.  , 2.  , 4.  , 4.  , 3.25],
       [4.  , 6.  , 8.  , 9.  , 3.  , 1.  , 1.  , 4.  , 4.5 ],
       [6.  , 6.  , 8.  , 9.  , 3.  , 1.  , 1.  , 4.  , 4.75],
       [4.57, 6.  , 8.  , 9.  , 3.  , 1.  , 1.  , 4.  , 4.57]])
```

Timings on bigger dataset -

```
In [150]: np.random.seed(0)

In [151]: data = np.random.randint(0,10,(5000,5000))

In [152]: %timeit fill0s(data,axis=0)
161 ms ± 4.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [153]: %timeit fill0s(data,axis=1)
155 ms ± 6.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#@yatu's solution
In [155]: %%timeit
     ...: m = data == 0
     ...: means = np.ma.array(data, mask = m).mean(0)
     ...: data + m * means.data
302 ms ± 3.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [156]: %%timeit
     ...: m = data == 0
     ...: means = np.ma.array(data, mask = m).mean(1)
     ...: data + m * means.data[:,None]
291 ms ± 2.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can it be filled by column wise as well?